# Grunt not loading external tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, workflow, frontend

I've hit a wall, so I'm hoping someone here can help me figure it out... I'm putting together a new Grunt stack that I can use across all my projects. However, for whatever reason, it's currently not loading tasks.

Here's my Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  var config = {
    pkg: require('package.json')
  };

  // Load all grunt configuration options
  grunt.util._.extend(config, loadConfig('./grunt/modules/'));

  // Configure grunt
  grunt.initConfig(config);

  // Load and register all tasks from devDependencies
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

  // Load all custom tasks
  grunt.loadTasks('grunt');

}

/**
 * Load configuration files for Grunt
 * @param   {string}  path  Path to folder with tasks
 * @return  {object}        All options
 *
 * http://thenittygritty.co/shared-grunt-configuration
 */
var loadConfig = function (path) {
  var glob = require('glob');
  var object = {};
  var key;

  glob.sync('*', { cwd: path }).forEach(function (option) {
    key = option.replace(/\.js$/,'');
    object[key] = require(path + option);
  });

  return object;
};
```

So, I have a "grunt" folder that contains all my custom, alias, and 3rd party tasks. Custom and alias tasks are in the main folder, while installed 3rd party tasks (cssmin.js, watch.js, etc) are in the "grunt/modules" folder.

Here's an example of a custom one and a 3rd party one...

**grunt/modules/connect.js:**

```
'use strict';

// https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect
module.exports = {

  dev: {
    options: {
      port: 6000,
      base: 'dist',
      livereload: true
    }
  }

}
```

**grunt/serve.js:**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.registerTask(
    'serve',
    [
      'build:dev',
      'connect',
      'watch'
    ]
  );

}
```

However, when I run "grunt serve" (or anything) I get a task not found error:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: undefined is not a function
Warning: Task "serve" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The issue actually didn't have anything to do with my Gruntfile... There was an issue in one of my tasks  that caused Grunt to fail. Once I sorted out that issue everything started working again.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. Feel free to mark this as the answer to close out the question.

Comment: @BrandonBoone Just have to wait another 9 hours before I can accept the answer... Though I feel dirty accepting my own non-answer, hah.